# WPF Fullscreen toggle still showing part of desktop

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to make a WPF app that loads fullscreen, and have the F11 key toggle between fullscreen and windowed.

With the following code, it first appears on the screen properly in fullscreen mode.  The toggle pulls it back down to a regular window.

Then the subsequent toggle it *almost* goes into fullscreen mode but seems shifted up by ~10 pixels, so half the taskbar is visible.  I'm able to reproduce this in a new WPF project with an empty main window.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
        this.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
        this.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
        this.Topmost = true;
        this.PreviewKeyDown +=
            (s, e) => {
                if (e.Key == Key.F11) {
                    if (this.WindowStyle == WindowStyle.None) {
                        this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
                        this.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.SingleBorderWindow;
                        this.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.CanResize;
                        this.Topmost = false;
                    } else {
                        this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
                        this.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
                        this.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
                        this.Topmost = true;
                    }
                }
            };
    }
}
```

Is this a bug in the framework?  I can't imagine it would have gone unnoticed until now but I've no idea what I'm doing wrong.  These are the properties that are supposed to do the job, and they're *almost* working but not quite.  I've tried messing around with other `Window` settings but no luck.  Any ideas?

Comment: I tried your code and it work fine form me, with a simple form and no components on it...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to this [WPF Discussion](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2009/05/03/wpf-discussion-090501.aspx), the order of setting the `WindowStyle` and `WindowState` matters.  You should set the `WindowStyle` before the `WindowState`

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
   public MainWindow()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
      this.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
      this.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.ToolWindow;
      this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
      this.Topmost = true;
      this.PreviewKeyDown +=
          (s, e) =>
          {
             if (e.Key == Key.F11)
             {
                if (this.WindowStyle != WindowStyle.SingleBorderWindow)
                {
                   this.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.CanResize;
                   this.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.SingleBorderWindow;
                   this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
                   this.Topmost = false;
                }
                else
                {
                   this.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
                   this.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.ToolWindow;
                   this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
                   this.Topmost = true;
                }
             }
          };
   }
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer! Kudos to @SwDevMan81!

Comment: This answer was very helpful, thank you. Note you can also use this.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None; instead of ToolWindow if you want full screen (kiosk) view.